# Why does raising the temperature affect the mass of dissolved solute?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

Consider a solution of $\ce{KOH}$ which is in equilibrium with undissolved $\ce{KOH}$ at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$.
After raising the temperature to $50\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, the mass of undissolved $\ce{KOH}$ decreases. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

For many (though not all) solids dissolved in water, solubility increases with temperature. The increase in kinetic energy that comes with higher temperatures allows the solvent molecules to more effectively break apart the intermolecular forces of the solute molecules.

For many salts and some gasses there are visual representations of solubility variation with temperature called a **solubility curve**, for which the units are $\frac{\mathrm{g~solute}}{\mathrm{100~g~solvent}}$. I could not find one for $\ce{KOH}$, but the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_hydroxide) for $\ce{KOH}$ lists the solubility of $\ce{KOH}$ at various temperatures, and it is clear the trend is that it is more soluble at higher temperatures.

As a result of Le Châtelier's principle, substances that release heat upon being dissolved tend to dissolve better in colder water. This accounts for gasses and some salts.

You should note, however, that although $\ce{KOH}$ does evolve a large amount of heat upon being dissolved, as the concentration of $\ce{KOH}$ increases, the process becomes less exothermic, and eventually near the saturation point it becomes endothermic (it becomes less favorable to dissolve more $\ce{KOH}$), which explains why it is more soluble at higher temperatures.

Comment: How can I relate the solubility with decreasing the mass of dissolved solute?

Comment: @user16139 edited to reflect your question

Comment: Apparently $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ has an exothermic heat of dissolution, yet its solubility is very low at room temperature and decreases further with increasing temperature. This seems to contrast with the explanation for the temperature behaviour of $\ce{KOH}$. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: I would suggest that $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$, unlike $\ce{KOH}$, becomes more exothermic or remains as exothermic at higher temperatures, and is therefore affected by Le Châtelier's principle in a way that makes it less soluble at higher temperatures.